# Download a PDF into android device download folder Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code in my activity that I use to generate a PDF file and save it into the device storage when I click a button I call saveFileToStorageIntent()

The problem that I am finding is that it is not downloaded automatically, instead, this opens another Document provider activity with save option. I want that the pdf file saves directly into Document folder from a single click on my application. What can I do to download the pdf directly to the device?

```
  private fun saveFileToStorageIntent() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    intent.type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "invoice.pdf")
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE)
  }

  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == CREATE_FILE) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        writePDFToFile(data.data, presenter.ticketResponse()!!)
      }
    }
  }

  private fun writePDFToFile(uri: Uri?, body: ResponseBody) {
    var inputStream: InputStream? = null
    var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
    try {
      val fileSize = body.contentLength()
      val fileReader = ByteArray(fileSize.toInt())
      var fileSizeDownloaded: Long = 0
      inputStream = body.byteStream()
      outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)
      while (true) {
        val read: Int = inputStream.read(fileReader)
        if (read == -1) {
          break
        }
        outputStream?.write(fileReader, 0, read)
        fileSizeDownloaded += read.toLong()
      }
      outputStream?.flush()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      Logger.print(TAG, e.message)
    } finally {
      if (inputStream != null) {
        try {
          inputStream.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
          e.printStackTrace()
        }
      }
      if (outputStream != null) {
        try {
          outputStream.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
          e.printStackTrace()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why are you talking about downloading? If yhat pdf on a server?

Comment: As with your other post you are not to the point.

Comment: Please put info in your post. You should write a better and readable post to begin with. Remove comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using `DownloadManager` for that?

```
 try{
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadPath);

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);  // Tell on which network you want to download file.
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);  // This will show notification on top when downloading the file.
            request.setTitle("Downloading data..."); // Title for notification.
            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
            request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "bearer my bearertoken"));
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, id+".pdf");
            ((DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)).enqueue(request); // This will start downloading
        }catch(Exception e){
            
        }
```

You can change the file path to `Downloads` in the above code.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it says the file was downloaded and it opens after the download, but when I search the file in the Downloads folder (I changed the file path to be there) it's not there

Comment: check out the following path: storage( check both sd and phone storage) > android > data > `your_app_package_name` > data